# How i can use Funcunit or Qunit to test my jQuery code in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery

How i can use FuncUnit or qunit to test my jQuery code.Can anyone exaplain how i can use one of them to test the jQuery code i write ?

Answer (score 1):

Funcunit is better for acceptance tests. It simulates user actions (mouse clicking, typing on a keyboard). Funcunit is an extension of QUnit.

If you realy need to test only your JavaScript code, in this case you can use e.g. [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/). It is faster then QUnit, because it doesn't manipulate with the DOM.
jQuery code is tested well, so you need not to duplicate this work by using of QUnit.